# Mount or extract data from LVM partiiton inside of a RAW IMG File?

Tags: partitioning, mount, lvm, linux-kvm, qemu

I have a raw disk .img file (running `file` indicates that it is a "DOS/MBR boot sector" file).

Running `mmls` produces the following output:

```
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

     Slot    Start        End          Length       Description
00:  Meta    0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)
01:  -----   0000000000   0000002047   0000002048   Unallocated
02:  00:00   0000002048   0000411647   0000409600   Linux (0x83)
03:  00:01   0000411648   0020971519   0020559872   Linux Logical Volume Manager (0x8e)
04:  -----   0020971520   0067108863   0046137344   Unallocated
```

When I try to mount partition "03", I get the error: `mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`

I can mount "02", but that just brings up a small MBR GRUB Parition.

Is there any way I can mount the LVM partition from the image file, or extract the data from it?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out out (thanks to this [thread](http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2008-June/msg00049.html)):

On an Ubuntu box with a GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install kpartx
sudo losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img
sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop0
```

Then, disk drives appear in the Nautilus file manager (GUI) under *Devices*.  Click on them to see the contents.

Comment: This answer really helped with recovering files from my daughter's laptop after a disk failure - thanks!